# CSS minimum header <h1, h2, h3> width next to floated image

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have headlines that should appear next to floated images if there is enough space, and drop below the images if not.  I don't have access to the HTML, so I must do this in strictly CSS.  This is an example of an image and headline HTML I receive, and what it ends up looking like on an iPhone, for example:

```
<p>
<img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com2852/1232.jpg" style="height:265px; width:350px; float: right;"/>
</p>
<h3>THE HEADLINE</h3>
```

[image: Don't want this.]

I've fixed this when it comes to wrapping `<p>` content around an image using the following trick, which creates a fixed width element before each paragraph which acts as a minimum width:

> p:before  {   content: "";   width: 10em;   display: block;   overflow:
>   hidden; }

However, this approach does not work for a header.  Any ideas?

Comment: Float both the image and the header to the same direction then just add a margin-left to the header?

Comment: I won't know what direction the image floats since I can't see the HTML in advance, nor if the headline has an associated image at all.

Comment: Any class I can anchor on in either the header or the image? If you can give me more sample HTML I can work with (as well as everyone else), it would help out immensely.

Comment: No, nothing i can depend on reliably.  I think there's a solution here using media-screens and checking if an image takes up a certain % of the screen width, and if so clearing the float so the entire headline drops down.  Make sense?

Comment: you probably mean "media queries" these are set rules the browser follows and not an "if checks" you can tell the browser to set some css rules when the screen width is at a certain size you pre-define.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Without a reliable HTML sample, I don't think we can effectively give you advice on how to solve this particular problem. Even if you can't change the HTML content coming from your source, you can pass it through a filter on your side, getting components via regex (yikes!), and then outputting it to a much more "normal" HTML that you can control. Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/zh4AV/1/

html:

```
<div id="container">
<img width="100" height="100"/>
<p>headline</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    max-width:200px;
}
img{
    float:right
}
```

Comment: Problem is I can't touch the HTML to insert that div container.

Comment: that container is not really important this example works even without it. I placed it in just to limit the movement a little so it doesn't stretch across the containing box.

Comment: If you change the headline text to "the headline", you'll see that "the" and "headline" get separated by the image.

Comment: Just won't work.  Messes up headers in other parts of the page, etc.